# Is it possible to compare time and things?

Tags: word-usage

> on preposition compared with somebody/something Sales are up on last
> year.

I don't understand why and how sales are up, compared to last year... I mean how time is up like sales? Moreover, it's preposition, so anything cannot be omitted between 'on' and 'last year.' Then, how can this sentence make sense?

[Preposition 'on'](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/on_1)

Comment: Your question is good. It is best answered on English Language  Learners Stack Exchange. The comparison is with an unstated noun phrase or similar thing. “Sales are up compared to {the sales of} last year”. When an obvious thought is missed from a sentence in this way it is called *ellipsis*.

Comment: @Anton Thank you! I've learnt that there could be omission even though it's not a conjunction thanks to you.

Comment: You are welcome. Please continue to use this site for any difficult questions. Easier ones will often be closed here and moved to ELL.